# Solr not use StandardTokenizerFactory if pattern

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm quite new to Solr(we use solr4), so sry if this question is dumb.

Everything works fine so far,
but our customer want his new product tags like this: 19.11.10
If we search vor this we don't find the product, but when we search for 19 11 10 we find every product with 19,11 and 10 in its tag.

As far as I get it, it's because of the "StandardTokenizerFactory" that filter out the ".".

Is there a option so I could still use "StandardTokenizerFactory" but get these pattern excluded?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you will need to make your own `fieldType` in `schema.xml` to narrow down the rules you want to have applied with your analyzer during the index and the query.

On [Indexing Special Terms Using Solr](http://www.prowaveconsulting.com/indexing-special-terms-using-solr/) (I am not related to this website) there is description on how to set up a `<fieldType name="text_tech" ... />`, which supports the search for special terms such as `Oracle 8i/9i/10g/11g` and `DB2/UDB`.

You could start by modifying this to fit your product tags, so that formats such as `19.11.10` would be recognized.